# How to change color of clicked button WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` that displays a list of buttons
I need to change color of button in the click while other buttons keep their initial color.

This is my code:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="80" Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What is the issue? What is the question?

Comment: I need to change background color in event click

Comment: Your code is working fine with me. Please explain the exact issue you're facing.

Comment: for example : i have list contains 3 elemnts , for each element have background red
i need to change the color of second elemnts (become green) but the others elemnt keep red
if i click in the first elemnt is in the necessary to chnage color of the first elemnt (become green) but the others element take init color (red)

Comment: You probably should maintain the state of your Collection elements in viewmodel, add a property to the collection item type that reflects the state (as enum, bool or whatever is appropriate) and bind that property to the Button backgroundcolor using a converter. Examples can be found on SO.

Comment: You could make it a listbox. Use selecteditem to drive your styling. Or use a radiobutton templated as a button and ischecked since that would be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @CongenitalOptimist Can you give me an example